# how map embedded in hibernate sql-query

Tags: java, hibernate

```
class A{
@Colunm(name = "id")
private long id;

@Embedded
private EmbeddedObject  embeddedObject;
}
@Embeddable
class EmbeddedObject{
private long b;
}
```

this is sql code without mapping embeded. I want fill b property in EmbeddedObject.
how map this???

```
<sql-query name="queryName">
    <return-scalar column="id" type="long"/>
        <![CDATA[
           select s.id id,
                from sample_table  s
        ]]>
</sql-query>
```

Comment: Why not just use HQL?